# Avoiding "text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored" in postgresql logs

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the texticle (https://github.com/tenderlove/texticle) library to do full-text postgresql searches.

The library generates sql like the following:

`to_tsvector('spanish', "games"."system"::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('spanish', 'Genesis'::text)`

If someone does a search for '&', then I get a warning in my logs:

`text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored`

How can I avoid this? Should I have the application know about the various stopwords and not send postgresql the query if the search term is comprised only of stopwords? Or can I tell postgresql to somehow ignore this warning?

Answer (score 1):

the warning is perfectly descriptive.  Basically you have to handle this somewhere in programming logic.  If your searches are in a stored procedure you can test the value and see if it contains lexemes.

Otherwise you can set the logging level to ERROR so warnings do not get set, or you can handle it on your application level.

None of these are perfect.  If I search for "the" I should get a similar warning so you probably want to be able to check after it is converted to a tsquery (i.e. in the database itself.

Otherwise, my advice is ignore the warning.

Comment: Chris I'm having issues with Chinese Full Text Search extension `ZHParser`, running the query `select title from knowledgebase_topics where to_tsvector('testzhcfg',title) @@ to_tsquery('testzhcfg','说话'); ` gets me error `text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored` even though my Chinese text contains lexemes - "说话" means speak. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659909/fts-non-latin-text-search-query-contains-only-stop-words-or-doesnt-contain-lex)

Answer (score 1):

This function could be used to resolve if query contains only stop words:

numnode(plainto_tsquery('spanish','&')) = 0 )

Answer (score -3):

personally i always sanitize user input. It should be considered evil for the most part. so in this case i would definitely do some filtering at the application level.

Comment: The user input is sanitized. But I don't think the filter should have knowledge of all the postgresql stop words.